# Django 1.9 Compiling Error

Tags: django, python-2.7

I created a virtualenv and downloaded Django with the below commands:

```
virtualenv tester
source tester/bin/activate
pip install django
```

and below is the response:

```
Downloading/unpacking django
  Downloading Django-1.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6MB): 6.6MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: django
Compiling /home/romaan/workspacepy/tester/build/django/django/conf/app_template/apps.py ...
  File "/home/romaan/workspacepy/tester/build/django/django/conf/app_template/apps.py", line 4
    class {{ camel_case_app_name }}Config(AppConfig):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Compiling /home/romaan/workspacepy/tester/build/django/django/conf/app_template/models.py ...
  File "/home/romaan/workspacepy/tester/build/django/django/conf/app_template/models.py", line 1
    {{ unicode_literals }}from django.db import models
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Successfully installed django
```

Please help me to get rid of this error. All though it says Successfully installed django, I am keen on understanding and getting rid of this syntax error.

Or Should I just wait for the bug fix to happen?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This looks like the setuptools issue mentioned in the Django 1.9 release notes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#syntaxerror-when-installing-django-setuptools-5-5-x

Try to run `pip install --upgrade pip` before running `pip install django`

Comment: If using pip3, should I run `pip3 install -U pip`? If so I think your answer could be improved by including that also.

Answer (score 1):

Those can't, and *shouldn't*, be fixed. Those are template files which are substituted at project creation time, and are not valid Python syntax. They shouldn't be compiled at install time but rather at project creation time.

Comment: I did not compile it, I just did pip install django @Igancio

Comment: The installation process is compiling it.

Comment: So should I simply wait for fix in next version or use previous version?

Answer (score 1):

These steps worked for me:

```
$ sudo python -m pip install --upgrade --force setuptools
$ sudo python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
$ sudo pip install django==1.9
```

Answer (score 0):

`pip install -U pip` ran fine but didn't fix my issue

- I got the same message when I was trying `pip install django`.
- I thought to try a previous version so I tried `pip install
  django-1.9`.
- It said "Real name of requirement Django-1.9 is django-503".
- So `pip install Django-503` worked fine for me.